# Is there a way to get the Docker Hub username of the current user?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I see that `~/.dockercfg` has your login credentials, but it is your email and not your username. I see that running `docker login` displays your username and prompts you to change it. But, you can you just get your username to put into a build script?

Comment: I don't see anything useful in the API docs. https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker-io_api/#user-login

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Update for modern Docker.

Seems that `docker info` no longer contains username. I have instead learned to extract it from the credential store via `jq`. I haven't tried this on every `credStore`, but for the ones I have checked on macOS and Linux, this works.

```sh
# line breaks added for readability; this also works as a oneliner
docker-credential-$(
  jq -r .credsStore ~/.docker/config.json
) list | jq -r '
  . |
    to_entries[] |
    select(
      .key | 
      contains("docker.io")
    ) |
    last(.value)
'
```

### [bonus] Show the entire contents of your credential helper

In this case I've settled on docker-credential-desktop, but it should work with any. You can extract your credential helper from your Docker config as I did in the previous code block.

```sh
docker-credential-desktop list | \
    jq -r 'to_entries[].key'   | \
    while read; do
        docker-credential-desktop get <<<"$REPLY";
    done
```

Comment: Wow, I've just seen my Docker.io password in plain text

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by `modern Docker`? could you please specify a docker version number ? I am using docker 20.10.7 and the username is still printed with `docker info`.  I would like to know if I need to prepare my scripts for future versions of docker or if we are using totally different software.  Thanks!

Comment: For PowerShell (Core Edition): `$credsStore = Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\.docker\config.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty credsStore &&
$dockerUser = &"docker-credential-$credsStore.exe" list | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values`.

Answer (score 20):

Display the username with:

```
docker info | sed '/Username:/!d;s/.* //'
```

Store it in a variable with:

```
username=$(docker info | sed '/Username:/!d;s/.* //'); 
echo $username
```

Note that if you have bash [history expansion](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/comment-page-1/) (`set +H`) you will be unable to put double quotes around the [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04) (e.g. `"$(cmd...)"` because `!` gets replaced with your last command. Escaping is very tricky with these nested expansions and using it unquoted as shown above is more readable and works.

Comment: I'll give you selected answer for the preferable use of `docker info` but I removed your useless use of grep. (Never combine a grep process with another that is capable of regex filtering.) http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#grep

Comment: Does not work on macOS - there is no username after logging in

Comment: `docker info` no longer display the username :(

Answer (score 0):

This works to extract it, but technically it's a race condition.

```
username="$(sed 's/.*(//;s/).*//' <(docker login & sleep 1; kill %1))"
```

Surely there is something better.